# I can't install any package

Tags: packages, latexmk

I want to use render some of the online templates in in vscode. But i am getting this error:

```
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 20 November 2021, version: 4.76.
Rule 'xelatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      '/home/osman/Downloads/LaTeXTemplates_developer-cv_v1.0/main.tex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'xelatex'
------------
------------
Running 'xelatex -no-pdf -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -shell-escape -recorder  "/home/osman/Downloads/LaTeXTemplates_developer-cv_v1.0/main.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'xelatex'...
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/home/osman/Downloads/LaTeXTemplates_developer-cv_v1.0/main.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22> (./developercv.cls
Document Class: developercv 2019/01/28 Developer CV class v1.0
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/extsizes/extarticle.cls
Document Class: extarticle 1996/10/08 v1.0 Non Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/extsizes/size9.clo) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/exscale.sty)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))

! LaTeX Error: File `moresize.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
./developercv.cls:44: Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.44 ^^M
        
No pages of output.
Transcript written on main.log.
Latexmk: Missing input file 'moresize.sty' (or dependence on it) from following:
  '! LaTeX Error: File `moresize.sty' not found.'
Latexmk: Log file says no output from latex
Latexmk: For rule 'xelatex', no output was made
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  xelatex: Command for 'xelatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'main.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
Latexmk: Examining 'main.log'
=== TeX engine is 'XeTeX'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

I assumed there are missing packages. But how can i resolve it? I can't install any package, because `tlmgr` is not installed.

So the question is:
How to install packages via command line or manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot find package **moresize**. Please make a directory like `mkdir -p ~/.texmf/tex/latex` then go to [CITAN web site](https://www.ctan.org) and search for moresize and go to the relevant link returned by its search engine and click on download link, it gives you a zip file containing the source and document files of the package, save it somewhere and unpack it in the directory you have created i.e. *~/.texmf/tex/latex*. Run this command `cd ~/.texmf/tex/latex && latex moresize.ins` it gives you the .sty file. Now to help **latexmk** find it create a file named .latexmkrc in the folder in which you put your .tex files here main.tex and add this line **ensure_path( 'TEXINPUTS', '~/.texmf//' );** to it and save it. It will make the trick.